# how can i add and remove modules from a custom component in joomla 1.5?

Tags: php, joomla

For instance, within a plugin run with the component, say I want to remove all the sidebar-a modules, resulting in it being collapsed. Or maybe I want to remove the first 3 modules and then add some other module or modules....

Basically, I want to control module inclusion/exclusion in the template from code...

Answer (score 0):

make there status unpublished(run a query to make the status of the extension 0 in jos_extension ) by your code in a particular condition so that they will not be taken into consideration in template position.If the page of your component disappears make the status 1 by running a another update query.

Comment: Thats a crafty idea, I rather like it, and done right it would work fine. Only trouble is when I come back in a year and need to make changes and the thing has a mind of it's own, ignoring my admin panel changes... Or worse someone else has to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the menu assignment to control the modules? Make menu items for the various pages in your component then assign the modules as required.

The problem you are going to run in to with trying to do it how you are describing is that you are going to have to parse HTML due to the order in which the framework builds a page. By the nature of Joomla you cannot control module positions from within the component. It can be done, but it's going to be very messy, especially considering that you can probably accomplish the same thing through menu assignments.

Comment: In the end, you were quite right. My problem had more to do with the way I was using Joomla. I was hardcoding (even if using SEF urls with JRouter::_('url')) and irritated because I didn't know or care what itemId to use and using none made all the homepage modules appear.

What I needed to do was the JMenu and JURL classes to generate the appropriate menu link and then use that in JRouter::(). Which always included the appropriate itemId.

So if anyone else gets any big ideas, like did.... Just go read the API and do it the Joomla way, it'll save you a fortune in time, that I lost =\